# Como importar cadastro de clientes para Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

migrei a minha loja virtual para Woocomerce.
Como faço para importar o cadastro dos clientes da minha antiga loja para o Woocomerce?

Comment: E qual era a sua antiga loja?